# Display then Delete Linked List C++

Tags: c++, linked-list

Our task is to display the linked list, then delete each node so if the function is called again it does not display anything. The list reads fine but I get stuck in an infinite loop and I'm not sure what's going on.

Here's the text file that gets read in to the struct (the first number is `acctNos` and the second is `Balance`)

```
98 45.70
72 15.0
12 0.0
56 43.26
83 123.0
28 931.96
123 12.38
```

```
struct familyFinance{
    int acctNos;
    float Balance;
    struct familyFinance* nextNodePointer;
};

void spitThemOut(struct familyFinance* &ptrHead)
{
    familyFinance* tempPtr;
    familyFinance* tempPtr2;
    tempPtr = ptrHead;
    tempPtr2 = ptrHead;

    while(tempPtr != nullptr)
    {
        cout<<"Acct, Balance: "<<temptPtr->acctNos<<" "<<tempPtr->Balance<<endl;
        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextNodePointer;
        delete tempPtr2;
        tempPtr2=nullptr;
    }
    ptrHead = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: _@Rachel96_ Post a [mcve] reproducing your problem as required here please.

Comment: This may help you for your future issues https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Pointers aren't like good deeds; more isn't necessarily better.

In your code, `tempPtr2` is pointless. If you're going to obliterate the list while printing it, just walk `ptrHead` down the list, capturing to `tempPtr` before advancing `ptrHead`, then delete it before the next iteration. That also eliminates the need for the hard-set of `ptrHead = nullptr;`

The result looks like this:

```
void spitThemOut(struct familyFinance* &ptrHead)
{
    while (ptrHead != nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Acct, Balance: " << ptrHead ->acctNos << " " << ptrHead ->Balance << endl;
        familyFinance *tempPtr = ptrHead;
        ptrHead = ptrHead->nextNodePointer;
        delete tempPtr;
    }
}
```